# Copy hypertext link from workbook to workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I basically export the datat contained in a first workbook to a second workbook, and it works fine except for hypertext links.

I export the data in two ways :

The first way is using an array that contain the data to export :

```
For m = 5 To 5 + k - 1
    openExport.Worksheets("Ind").Cells(lastrow + 2, m).Value = headerExportArray(m - 5)
Next m
```

The second way is to do it directly from workbook to workbook :

```
newWorkBook1.Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(1, i + 5 + k) = OldWorkbook.Worksheets("Valeurs").Cells(15, i + 2)
```

So I would like to know how I can export the hypertextlinks using the two methods described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the hyperlink text and address through the `Hyperlinks` collection of your `Range`. For example, if you want to access the address of the link, you can call:

```
Cells(x,y).Hyperlinks(1).Address
```

Copying a hyperlink then simply becomes a matter of extracting the needed attributes from the original link and adding a new one to the target range using [Range.Hyperlinks.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490.aspx).

Comment: I get a "Subscript out of range" error message (error 9) when I try to use `Cells(x,y).Hyperlinks(1).Address` @DanL

Comment: You must replace x and y with the address of the cell you're copying from :-)

Comment: Besides, you'll also need to check whether the cell actually contains a hyperlink.

Comment: Hint: Hyperlinks.Count ;-)

Comment: You can actually use the **Hyperlinks** collection under the Worksheet.